Replace existing column with merged column and rename
I am merging two dataframes. The first dataframe looks like this:
A       B        C           D
party1  asset1   product1    Buy
party1  asset1   product2    Sell
party2  asset2   product1    Buy
party2  asset2   product2    Sell

The second dataframe looks like this:
A       B        D
party1  asset1   Buy
party1  asset1   Sell
party2  asset2   Buy
party2  asset2   Sell

I merge the dataframes like this:
df2 = df.merge(df1, on=['A', 'B', 'D'])

which returns:
A       B        D      C
party1  asset1   Buy    product1
party1  asset1   Sell   product2
party2  asset2   Buy    product1
party2  asset2   Sell   product2

I need to replace the values in column 'B' with the values in column 'C' while keeping the same name 'B'.
A       B          D      
party1  product1   Buy    
party1  product2   Sell   
party2  product1   Buy    
party2  product2   Sell   

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would help.

the reason I can't use the first data frame is because it is static.  DF2 data is coming from spreadsheets

Just pop C to replace B:
df2 = df.merge(df1, on=['A', 'B', 'D'])
df2['B'] = df1.pop('C')

As chained operations:
df2 = (df.merge(df1, on=['A', 'B', 'D'])
         .assign(B=lambda x: x.pop('C'))
      )

Output:
        A         B     D      
0  party1  product1   Buy    
1  party1  product2  Sell   
2  party2  product1   Buy    
3  party2  product2  Sell

